# Shiny Server: Generating downloadable PDF fails during compilation (code operational locally)

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, r-markdown, knitr, shiny-server

I am hosting a Shiny Application ("alpha") on a remote Ubuntu 16.04 LTS platform. When uploading a Shiny App directory that is fully operational when run locally, the generate .pdf function does not work. In particular, the browser returns the following error message;

> Firefox can’t find the file at http://IP/alpha/session/88c0e307e045e4b519908a73b85476f4/download/report?w=.

I first suspected that this is a user entitlements issue, and gifted the "Shiny" user (which runs the application by default on Ubuntu) read-write-exec access to the /tmp/ folder considering that the .pdf generation uses a temporary folder to generate the report.

```
sudo setfacl -m 'u:shiny:rwx' /tmp/
```

Unfortunately, the problem remains. Below are my package versions:

```
knitr        "knitr"        "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "1.20"
rmarkdown    "rmarkdown"    "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "1.10"  
shiny        "shiny"        "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "1.1.0"
tinytex      "tinytex"      "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "0.8"
/opt/shiny-server/ext/pandoc/pandoc --version pandoc 1.19.2.1
```

The Pandoc package was compiled upon the installation of Shiny Server, and the TinyTex package was installed by following https://yihui.name/tinytex/.

Here is the error log produced by Shiny Server:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43458
165: ispresent
164: scatter3D
163: renderPlot [/srv/shiny-server/alpha/server.R#254]
161: func
121: drawPlot
107: <reactive:plotObj>
91: drawReactive
78: origRenderFunc
77: output$dist
1: runApp

processing file: report.Rmd
output file: report.knit.md

sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
Warning: Error in : Failed to compile /tmp/Rtmp25Y4aU/file5bf19f9dd9f.tex. [No stack trace available]
```

I am attaching the downloadHandler below. As stated before, it is **fully operational** locally.

```
output$report = downloadHandler(

                  filename = 'xxx.pdf',

                  content = function(file) {

                    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
                    file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

                    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
                    params <- list(mat = allocation_values$rendered[allocation_values$rendered$Allocation > 0])

                    rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                                      params = params,
                                      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))

                  })
```

EDIT: Added output of > tinytex::tlmgr_conf()

```
=========================== version information ==========================
tlmgr revision 48522 (2018-08-31 06:03:37 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /root/.TinyTeX
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2018
==================== executables found by searching PATH =================
PATH: /root/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dvipdfmx:  /root/bin/dvipdfmx
dvips:     0
fmtutil:   /root/bin/fmtutil
kpsewhich: /root/bin/kpsewhich
luatex:    /root/bin/luatex
mktexpk:   /root/bin/mktexpk
pdftex:    /root/bin/pdftex
tex:       0
tlmgr:     /root/bin/tlmgr
updmap:    /root/bin/updmap
xetex:     /root/bin/xetex
=========================== active config files ==========================
Missing argument in sprintf at /root/bin/tlmgr line 6159.
config.ps:        fmtutil.cnf:      /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktex.cnf:        /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/mktex.cnf
pdftexconfig.tex: /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex
texmf.cnf:        /root/.TinyTeX/texmf.cnf
texmf.cnf:        /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
updmap.cfg:       /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
============================= font map files =============================
kanjix.map:  /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map
pdftex.map:  /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
ps2pk.map:   /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
psfonts.map: /root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
ENCFONTS=.:{/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
SYSTEXMF=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var:/root/texmf-local:/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist
TEXCONFIG={/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}/dvips//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
TEXMF={/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}
TEXMFCONFIG=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config
TEXMFDBS={!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}
TEXMFDIST=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist
TEXMFHOME=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home
TEXMFLOCAL=/root/texmf-local
TEXMFMAIN=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
VARTEXFONTS=/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/fonts
WEB2C={/usr/share/R/share/texmf,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-home,!!/root/texmf-local,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-config,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-var,!!/root/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist}/web2c
==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear that pdflatex was not found. How did you install TinyTeX precisely?

Comment: First attempt:
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()

Installation verified through:
tinytex:::is_tinytex()
[1] TRUE

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `tinytex::tlmgr_conf()`. In addition: Which user ran those commands? Which user runs the Shiny server?

Comment: Log added. The "Shiny" user runs the server by default. @RalfStubner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shows that `pdflatex` is not found:

```
sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
```

In the output of `tinytex::tlmgr_conf()` we see that `pdftex` is installed in `/root`, i.e. the HOME directory of the `root` user:

```
pdftex:    /root/bin/pdftex
```

It looks as if you executed `tinytex::install_tinytex()` as `root` user.
The `shiny` user, which runs the Shiny server, has no access to that directory. You can add a TinyTeX installation for the `shiny` user like this:

```
sudo su - shiny
R -e 'tinytex::install_tinytex()'
```

I do not know if it is possible to make a system-wide installation using `tinytex`.

Comment: This is excellent. I had the idea that tinytex was system-wide (alike standard R-libraries installed through install.packages()). Many thanks, have a good day! Upvoted answer, although my rep won't show it.